# WPF Modifying an UIElement on a MouseEnter Event

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I use WPF. I've got a Grid inside a border and i would like to let show a button inside my grid (otherwise invisible) when a mouseEnter is fired.

I'm able to drag this border around playing with e.GetPosition(myCanvas).X or Y to move the thing in an all.

Now I try to access my button inside my Grid to let it show and i'm stuck.

In my MouseEnter event I do :

```
UIElement source = (UIElement)sender;
```

But i can't "dissociate" the source ... there is no Children collection.

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Border class has no Children property but it has a Child property that you can cast to a Grid provided that the child of the Border is actually a Grid:

```
Border border = (Border)sender;
Grid grid = border.Child as Grid;
if (grid != null)
{
    Button button = grid.Children[0] as Button;
    if(button != null)
       button.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

This code should work if you are handling the MouseEnter event for the Border element and the Grid inside the Border contains a Button element. If you are handling the Grid's MouseEnter element you should of course cast the sender argument to a Grid directly.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a DependencyProperty on the form, that you can bind the visibility property of the button to. And then in the MouseEnter and MouseLeave of the border, and set the DependencyProperty.

Comment: Thank you Rick,

i didn't know anthing about DependencyProperties. I put that on top of my Todo list

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think about doing mouseenter on the grid. It works like charm.
I can now going on.

```
Grid sourceG = (Grid)sender;
sourceG.Children[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```